# How find this $V=A^{-1}(0)\bigoplus B^{-1}(0)$

Tags: linear-algebra

The $n-$dimension of the vector space V over the field $P$ ,and let $A$ and $B$ is $V$ a linear transformation,such $$A^2=0,B^2=0,AB+BA=I$$
show that
$$V=A^{-1}(0)\bigoplus B^{-1}(0)$$

My try:$\forall \alpha\in V$, then
$$AB\alpha+BA\alpha=\alpha$$
and since
$$AB\alpha\in V,BA\alpha\in V$$
and
$$A(AB\alpha)=A^2(B\alpha)=0,B(BA\alpha)=B^2(A\alpha)=0$$
so
$$A^{-1}(0)=\{AB\alpha|A(AB\alpha)=0,AB\alpha\in V\}$$
$$B^{-1}(0)=\{BA\alpha|B(BA\alpha)=0,BA\alpha\in V\}$$
and I can't prove 
$$A^{-1}(0)\bigcap B^{-1}(0)=\emptyset$$

Thank you for your help

Comment: If $Ax = 0$ and $Bx = 0$, what is $(AB+BA)(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v \in V$ is such that $v \in A^{-1}(0) \cap B^{-1}(0)$, then $v=Iv=ABv+BAv=0$.

Comment: Oh,Thank you.I forget